# How to rove that $S_{ALD}/S_{EKC}=(AB*AD)/(BC*CE)$ in figure with right angles?

Tags: geometry

Points L, D, E, and K are collinear and angles L, D, E, K are right-angles. Prove that $S_{ALD}/S_{EKC}=(AB*AD)/(BC*CE)$.
[image]

I marked the sides with letters to make it easier and wrote the theorems of Pythagorean to these rectangular triangles I have a lot of equations but I do not know what to do next, maybe something else is needed?

Answer (score 0):

This can be proved by similarity. Assign angles
$$\angle LAB=\beta \space and \space \angle BAE=\alpha$$
You can see that
$$\triangle LAD \space \sim \space \triangle KDC \space and \space \triangle LAE \sim \triangle KEC$$
From those two similarities we get $$ \frac{LD}{CK}=\frac{AD}{CD} \space (1) \space and \space \frac {LA}{EK}=\frac {AE}{CE} \space (2) \space respectively.$$It is sufficient to prove that $$\frac {AB}{BC}=\frac {AE}{CD} \space (3)$$ The above expression is true since $$\triangle BAE \space \sim \space \triangle BCD $$ Multiplying (1) by (2) and using (3) we get the prove.